# Exception: DTD must be defined before the document root element

Tags: c#, xml, dtd

I am generating an XML document in the following code. At line

```
xmlDocument.LoadXml(end);
```

throws exception saying: *DTD must be defined before the document root element*

So i found xmlDocument.DocumentType is null and realized Document Type Definition(DTD) must be added to the xmldocument object. so i added

```
 xmlDocument.CreateDocumentType("sample", null, null, null);
```

But still it throws same exception.

**CODE:**

```
            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument()
            {
                PreserveWhitespace = true
            };
            XmlElement soap = SoapUtil.ToSoap(samlMessage.GetXml(), xmlDocument);
            xmlDocument.AppendChild(soap);
            object[] outerXml = new object[] { xmlDocument.OuterXml };
            SamlTrace.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "SOAP request to send: {0}", outerXml);
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
            webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://oasis-open.org/committees/security");
            using (Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                xmlDocument.Save(requestStream);
            }
            using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string end = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    SamlTrace.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "Received SOAP response message: {0}", new object[] { end });
-------->           xmlDocument.LoadXml(end); //exception thrown at this line
                }
            }
            XmlElement xmlElement1 = SoapUtil.FromSoap(xmlDocument.DocumentElement);
            object[] objArray = new object[] { xmlElement1.OuterXml };
            SamlTrace.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "Response converted from SOAP message: {0}", objArray);
            xmlElement = xmlElement1;
```

Update 1:

```
 xmlDocument.LoadXml(streamReader.ReadToEnd().ToString());
```

i passed streamReader and converting it to a string.
Now it throws a new exception.

"*Root element is missing.*"

Comment: Why not just use :  xmlDocument.Load(requestStream);

Comment: Load expects a string and we need to load responsestream.

Comment: Wrong!!!  Load take either a string or a stream.

Comment: hi @jdweng i can pass a string alone as a parameter. streamReader is Invalid argument it throws. i can pass it after converting using Tostring() and I have updated my question.

Comment: You don't need streamreader!!!  Xml Document Load method takes a stream.  In this case the response.GetResponseStream.

Comment: What is the value of `end`? It looks a lot like the XML you're getting back isn't valid.